# How can I get the value of previous dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select dropdown and a textfield. I want to create a JSON based on the value out of the value of textfield and dropdown.

```
<select>
 <option value="English">English</option>
 <option value="Kannada">Kannada</option>
 <option value="Hindi">Hindi</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="Ivrgroupzbase_languageWelcomeURL" name="Ivrgroupzbase[languageWelcomeURL]" cols="50" rows="6">
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oeuuo7jp/1/)
How can I find the selected value from previous dropdown using jQuery

Comment: from 'previous dropdown' means????

Comment: Hello. What do you understand by previous dropdown you have only one? You mean previous value in dropdown?

Comment: I'm working on add/remove textfields, where I have an array of dropdown and textfield

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('#Ivrgroupzbase_languageWelcomeURL').prev('select').find(':selected').val();
```

Full example [in updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oeuuo7jp/4/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#Ivrgroupzbase_languageWelcomeURL').on("keyup", function(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            $('#value').html($(this).val() + " " + $(this).prev('select').find(':selected').val());
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you say `previous dropdown` you means the previous `<select>` element of your `<input>` so you can use:

`var select=$("#Ivrgroupzbase_languageWelcomeURL").prev("select").val();`

Comment: Interesting to get to know that selected value can be obtained even without `:selected`, thanks.

Comment: It's from jquery api: http://api.jquery.com/val/ , in this url there are the next sample: `// Get the value from a dropdown select`
`$( "select.foo option:selected").val();`
 
`// Get the value from a dropdown select even easier`
`$( "select.foo" ).val();`

Comment: Yeah, I checked documentation and found that it is really so, right after I've seen your answer